# How to create dependency property of BindingList<dynamic>

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, bindinglist

I'm creating auto-complete with details using `TextBox` and `DataGrid` which can accept any list `[Binding List]` and search based on `TextBox`.

However, I cannot create a dependency property for a dynamic object. I get `null` instead of `list`.

`BindingList<some_object>` works fine, but then I can't bind other types of lists to that control.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show some code on what you did and what you tried that doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use BindingList as property type. Instead, use the most basic possible type, most likely `IEnumerable` as e.g. the ItemsSource property of class ItemsControl.

Comment: Nice idea. Ok i'll notify @Clrmens